# What is the meaning of "Avoid piling that places this specimen under pressure."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was talking to a translator about the following sentence

> "Avoid piling that places this specimen under pressure."

She suggested that it means

> "Trying not to pile up this specimen so that it does not corrupt
>   because of the pressure."

Does it make sense? It sounds to me

> "Do colorless Ideas sleep furiously."

Comment: Are you writing a label to put on a cardboard specimen box? By "piling" do we mean stacking on a shelf or a bunch of parcels thrown into the back of a mail truck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what "piling" means. It could mean the act of putting things in a pile, or it could be the things in the pile itself. "Piling" has a few other meanings as well.

The sentence does not specify what's in the pile. It could be a pile of boxes on top of the specimen. Or a pile of specimens on top of other specimens. Or a chunk of ice on top of the specimen. Or anything at all that can be put in a pile.

What is clear is that you do not want to put pressure on the specimen. This means avoid stacking anything on top because of gravity, but it implies that the specimen is fragile and could be damaged by pressure from any direction.

Comment: Thank you for very clear explanation. She said that the thing in the pile itself. But it was still hard for me to get this sentence of meaning. Because "piling" has some other different meanings. Yes, the last paragraph of your explanation was the model answer implying. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this message will be written on a box.

Boxes intended to be stacked, perhaps in a warehouse often say things like:

> Do not stack more than five high.

If the message is for a postman, it might say:

> Specimen. Do not crush.

A longer version might be:

> Specimen. Avoid crushing under other parcels.

Your translator suggested:

> Trying not to pile up this specimen so that it does not corrupt because of the pressure.

As you suspect, this makes no sense. Corrected it would read:

> Try not to pile things on top of this specimen so that it is not damaged by the weight.

The imperative is "try", not "trying". To understand the difference, consider these examples:

> Try to sleep.
>
> He is trying to sleep.

To "pile up" would mean to make a pile out of the specimen. One specimen is not enough to make a pile.

The risk is that the specimen could be damaged, not that it might corrupt someone or something. It will not offer a judge a bribe if you crush it.

Comment: Thank you for your very specific explanation. Yes. I think the word "corrupt" was not appropriate to describe this situation. And imperative should be described as you mentioned above.Original sentence of gerund "piling" was really obscure to me.However you explained here in detail here, it makes sense to me better. Thanks for answering. I really appreciate it!